# How to configure PHP under Apache web server in GENTOO Operating System?

Tags: php, apache, gentoo, mod-php

is there anyone who knows how to install / configure php under apache?

I have emerge php apache both.
I wanted to use mod_php for apache in GENTOO OS.

php temp.php

command line runs fine, but http://localhost/temp.php is not executing on web server instead it shows the content of the php code.

Comment: Gentoo isn't an acronym. It's a type of penguin, actually.

Comment: *"Their super-streamlined bodies make them the **fastest penguin** underwater"* in http://www.bbc.co.uk/nature/life/Gentoo_Penguin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a blog and I followed his instruction and it works !
I'm sharing the solution [Referenced Blog](http://tronprog.blogspot.com/2007/02/apache2-php-mysql-gentoo-linux.html)

I put these lines in /etc/make.conf:

```
USE="apache2 mysql php pam ssl xml xml2 berkdb innodb jpeg png"
```

If you want to install also phpmyadmin, then you should also add pcre session unicode:

```
USE="apache2 mysql php pam ssl xml xml2 berkdb innodb jpeg png pcre session unicode"
```

I then changed the file /etc/init.d/apache2, in order to enable public_html folders for users (corresponding to the ~ directory), setting -D USERDIR:

```
APACHE2_OPTS="-D DEFAULT_VHOST -D PHP5 -D USERDIR
```

Before starting mysql, you must create (once and for all) the mysql main database, and this can be done simply by running:

```
/usr/bin/mysql_install_db
```

Comment: -1: putting single-package USE flags in /etc/make.conf is strongly discouraged, as they will be applied to the whole system (which might cause problems with dependencies and such).

Comment: I think you meant changing `/etc/conf.d/apache2` not `/etc/init.d/apache2`.

Comment: echo "dev-lang/php apache2 my sql php pam ssl [...]" >> /etc/portage/package.use is an example how to specify per-package use flags.  apache, php, and mysql will need added with specific use flags if you decide not to have them as global flags. After emerging gentoolkit, equery uses dev-lang/php will give you a description of available use flags for this package.  I also find equery files [package] use-full.

Comment: This answer is correct, but more than most people will probably need.  The real key here is adding "-D PHP5" to APACHE2_OPTS in /etc/conf.d/apache2 then restarting via /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Comment: @JulianBayardoSpadafora Hey if you've rights to update the answer - kindly make those changes.

Comment: I had to add the `pdo` use flag, but otherwise this worked for me in 2023.

Answer (score 4):

There appear to be a number of ways to achieve this but many seem a bit out of date or overly complicated.  As of Feb 1 2010 all I did to get PHP and Apache2 working on Gentoo was to install Apache and PHP like this:

1. `bash$ emerge apache`
2. Followed the instructions for the particular extensions I wanted at [this list at the Gentoo site](http://overlays.gentoo.org/proj/php/wiki/ManagingExtensions)

   - NOTE: this is the important one to get Apache and PHP working together:

     - `bash$ echo "dev-lang/php apache2" >> /etc/portage/package.use`
   - Another common PHP extension:

     - `bash$ echo "dev-lang/php mysql" >> /etc/portage/package.use`
   - And so on.
3. Then just run `bash$ emerge dev-lang/php` and restart Apache with the /etc/init.d/apache2 script.  PHP should now be available.

Answer (score 1):

You may find some informations in [Apache 2.0 on Unix systems](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php)

Especially, the

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
```

and

```
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
```

Lines should help :-)

The corresponding lines I have in my Apache's configuration (Apache 2, PHP 5.2, Ubuntu) are :

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp-5.2.9.so
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml
  AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

above link dead, try this one:

http://overlays.gentoo.org/proj/php/

Answer (score -1):

Try to use official GENTOO documentation:

http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/php/php4-php5-configuration.xml

Comment: that is only for running two php versions concurrently